# Tab on div [CSS]

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make tab like this in pure css?

[image: simple tab]

Comment: Yes! it is possible.

Comment: You can find code to banners like this online, I think google something like "CSS pop out banner" and see what comes up

Comment: I understand, but how to call it to find?

Comment: Any of these two links have it, you'd just remove the bits on the ends:
[link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/) and [link](https://codepen.io/Protohominid/pen/qLuEx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CSS3 pseudo classes` for this. Check snippet below..

```css
.ribbon {
 font-size: 16px !important;
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 background: #ccc;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 2em; 
 margin: 2em auto 3em;
} 
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #999 transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 left: 0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="ribbon">
   <strong class="ribbon-content">xyz</strong>
</h1>
```

Comment: That's not an answer. He asked if it's possible, not how to do it.

Comment: Great, thank you! How to make it responsive? When it is placed on white div it has different width on each resolution. Should I set constant width in px and modify it in media queries?

Comment: I have set width `200px` on `ribbon` div, you can set this width as per you requirement.